# Filtering out array elements if element contains specified string in hive/SparkSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, json, apache-spark-sql, hive

I have sample data like below, I want to extract the elements which have only names and its completed keys not dep_names and its completed key.

I'm trying something like below:

```
WITH dataset AS 
(
   SELECT '{"name": "Bob Smith",
             "org": "engineering",
             "projects": [{"dep_namename":"project1", "completed":none},{"name":"project2", "completed":false},{"name":"project3", "completed":true}]}'
    AS myblob
)
SELECT get_json_object(myblob, '$.projects[*]?(exists(@.name))' AS project_name
FROM dataset
```

I'm expecting output like below

```
[false,true]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below `Spark SQL`

```
SELECT 
    FILTER(
        FROM_JSON(
            input,
            'projects array<struct<dep_namename:string, completed:string, name:string>>'
        ).projects, 
        mp -> mp.name IS NOT NULL
    ).completed as output 
FROM VALUES 
 ('{"name": "Bob Smith","org": "engineering","projects": [{"dep_namename":"project1", "completed":"none"},{"name":"project2", "completed":false},{"name":"project3", "completed":true}]}') 
AS (input)

+-------------+
|output       |
+-------------+
|[false, true]|
+-------------+
```

OR

```
SELECT 
    FILTER(
        FROM_JSON(
            input,
            'projects array<struct<dep_namename:string, completed:string, name:string>>'
        ).projects.completed, 
        completed -> completed <> 'none' OR completed IS NULL      
    ) as output 
FROM VALUES 
    ('{"name": "Bob Smith","org": "engineering","projects": [{"dep_namename":"project1", "completed":"none"},{"name":"project2", "completed":false},{"name":"project3", "completed":true}]}') 
AS (input)
```